# Unexpected EOF from Docker Registry

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I’m receiving an unexpected EOF (I think) when I try to get to the Docker registry during a docker pull. I am trying to pull the mongo image, but I get the same message for any docker image. Here is the message from Power Shell.

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: EOF.
```

I found [this post](https://forums.docker.com/t/unexpected-eof-on-auth-docker-io-when-trying-to-pull-from-docker-hub/90652) from earlier this year, but as far as I can tell, I don’t have docker-cli installed in wsl:

```
wsl --list --verbose
NAME                STATE    VERSION
Debian              running  2
docker-desktop      running  2
docker-desktop-data running  2
```

I have uninstalled and reinstalled both docker and wsl twice. Same result every time. It’s not a proxy/firewall issue. `curl https://registry-1.docker.io` returns a 200. `curl https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/` returns a 403, which seems normal to me since I’m not specifying any kind of file or page.

Any help is appreciated.